# Image not exporting when making runnable jar

Tags: java, swing, jar, embedded-resource, system-tray

In my project I use the system tray, when I compile the program everything is working fine and the icon that I use for the system tray shows up.

The icon is placed in the project folder and the code related to the icon is

```
Image icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Icon.png");

trayIcon = new TrayIcon(icon, "Program name", popup);
trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);

tray.add(trayIcon);
```

As I said, everything works find but when I export the project as a runnable jar the program will run but the icon will not show up, but it will just be blank.

Comment: Make sure you include it in the list of files, but then use a resource loader from the class to load the image.

Comment: I hope this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230) might be of some use for this situation

Answer (score 6):

If you would like to  load resources from your .jar file use `getClass().getResource()`. That returns a URL with correct path.

```
Image icon = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("image´s path"));
```

Answer (score 5):

To access images in a jar, use [`Class.getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29).

I typically do something like this:

```
InputStream stream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("Icon.png");
if(stream == null) {
   throw new RuntimeException("Icon.png not found.");
}

try {
   return ImageIO.read(stream);
} catch (IOException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
} finally {
   try {
      stream.close();
   } catch(IOException e) { }
}
```